# Signers are being required to sign tabs meant for other recipients

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am integrating docusign into an app using the python SDK with the flow as follows:

1.) generate an envelope with multiple documents each with its own tabs

2.) The envelope has 3 recipients( 2 signers with routing order and 1 cc)

3.) In each document there are 2 tabs groups for each signer in the envelope.

4.) Once the first signer signs all documents, the envelope is sent to the second to sign.

The routing order is working just fine but the issue I am having is, the first signer is forced to sign all tabs in the envelope even ones that are attached to second signer. The same goes for the second signer. Because of this the date_signed tabs are wrongly populated when the document is signed.

here is the JSON data for the recipients in the envelope definition

```
{
 'recipients': {
                'signers': [
                    {   
                             'client_user_id': None,
                             'completed_count': None,
                             'email': 'test1@test1.com',
                             'name': 'egeg feefe',
                             'name_metadata': None,
                             'recipient_attachments': None,
                             'recipient_id': 72295,
                             'recipient_id_guid': None,
                             'role_name': None,
                             'routing_order': '1',
                             'tabs': {
                                      'sign_here_tabs': [{'anchor_allow_white_space_in_characters': None,
                                                          'anchor_allow_white_space_in_characters_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_case_sensitive': None,
                                                          'anchor_case_sensitive_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_ignore_if_not_present': None,
                                                          'anchor_ignore_if_not_present_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_match_whole_word': True,
                                                          'anchor_match_whole_word_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_string': '/222c/',
                                                          'anchor_string_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_tab_processor_version': None,
                                                          'anchor_tab_processor_version_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_units': 'pixels',
                                                          'anchor_units_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_x_offset': '20',
                                                          'anchor_x_offset_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_y_offset': '20',
                                                          'anchor_y_offset_metadata': None,
                                                          'caption': None,
                                                          'caption_metadata': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_label': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_value': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_value_metadata': None,
                                                          'custom_tab_id': None,
                                                          'custom_tab_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'document_id': None,
                                                          'document_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'error_details': None,
                                                          'form_order': None,
                                                          'form_order_metadata': None,
                                                          'form_page_label': None,
                                                          'form_page_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'form_page_number': None,
                                                          'form_page_number_metadata': None,
                                                          'hand_draw_required': None,
                                                          'height': None,
                                                          'height_metadata': None,
                                                          'is_seal_sign_tab': None,
                                                          'merge_field': None,
                                                          'merge_field_xml': None,
                                                          'name': None,
                                                          'name_metadata': None,
                                                          'optional': None,
                                                          'optional_metadata': None,
                                                          'page_number': None,
                                                          'page_number_metadata': None,
                                                          'recipient_id': 72295,
                                                          'recipient_id_guid': None,
                                                          'recipient_id_guid_metadata': None,
                                                          'recipient_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'scale_value': None,
                                                          'scale_value_metadata': None,
                                                          'smart_contract_information': None,
                                                          'source': None,
                                                          'stamp': None,
                                                          'stamp_type': None,
                                                          'stamp_type_metadata': None,
                                                          'status': None,
                                                          'status_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_group_labels': None,
                                                          'tab_group_labels_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_id': None,
                                                          'tab_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_label': '/222c/',
                                                          'tab_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_order': None,
                                                          'tab_order_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_type': None,
                                                          'tab_type_metadata': None,
                                                          'template_locked': None,
                                                          'template_locked_metadata': None,
                                                          'template_required': None,
                                                          'template_required_metadata': None,
                                                          'tool_tip_metadata': None,
                                                          'tooltip': None,
                                                          'width': None,
},
                                                         {'anchor_allow_white_space_in_characters': None,
                                                          'anchor_allow_white_space_in_characters_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_case_sensitive': None,
                                                          'anchor_case_sensitive_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_ignore_if_not_present': None,
                                                          'anchor_ignore_if_not_present_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_match_whole_word': True,
                                                          'anchor_match_whole_word_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_string': '/333d/',
                                                          'anchor_string_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_tab_processor_version': None,
                                                          'anchor_tab_processor_version_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_units': 'pixels',
                                                          'anchor_units_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_x_offset': '20',
                                                          'anchor_x_offset_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_y_offset': '20',
                                                          'anchor_y_offset_metadata': None,
                                                          'caption': None,
                                                          'caption_metadata': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_label': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_value': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_value_metadata': None,
                                                          'custom_tab_id': None,
                                                          'custom_tab_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'document_id': None,
                                                          'document_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'error_details': None,
                                                          'form_order': None,
                                                          'form_order_metadata': None,
                                                          'form_page_label': None,
                                                          'form_page_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'form_page_number': None,
                                                          'form_page_number_metadata': None,
                                                          'hand_draw_required': None,
                                                          'height': None,
                                                          'height_metadata': None,
                                                          'is_seal_sign_tab': None,
                                                          'merge_field': None,
                                                          'merge_field_xml': None,
                                                          'name': None,
                                                          'name_metadata': None,
                                                          'optional': None,
                                                          'optional_metadata': None,
                                                          'page_number': None,
                                                          'page_number_metadata': None,
                                                          'recipient_id': 4804,
                                                          'recipient_id_guid': None,
                                                          'recipient_id_guid_metadata': None,
                                                          'recipient_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'scale_value': None,
                                                          'scale_value_metadata': None,
                                                          'smart_contract_information': None,
                                                          'source': None,
                                                          'stamp': None,
                                                          'stamp_type': None,
                                                          'stamp_type_metadata': None,
                                                          'status': None,
                                                          'status_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_group_labels': None,
                                                          'tab_group_labels_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_id': None,
                                                          'tab_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_label': '/333d/',
                                                          'tab_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_order': None,
                                                          'tab_order_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_type': None,
                                                          'tab_type_metadata': None,
                                                          'template_locked': None,
                                                          'template_locked_metadata': None,
                                                          'template_required': None,
                                                          'template_required_metadata': None,
                                                          'tool_tip_metadata': None,
                                                          'tooltip': None,
                                                          'width': None,
}],
                                                        },
                                                    },
                            {
                             'client_user_id': None,
                             'completed_count': None,
                             'email': 'ftt.tttvb@gmail.com',
                             'name': 'Dan Kerbon',
                             'name_metadata': None,
                             'recipient_attachments': None,
                             'recipient_id': 4804,
                             'recipient_id_guid': None,
                             'role_name': None,
                             'routing_order': '2',
                             'tabs': {
                                        'sign_here_tabs': [{'anchor_allow_white_space_in_characters': None,
                                                          'anchor_allow_white_space_in_characters_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_case_sensitive': None,
                                                          'anchor_case_sensitive_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_ignore_if_not_present': None,
                                                          'anchor_ignore_if_not_present_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_match_whole_word': True,
                                                          'anchor_match_whole_word_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_string': '/222c/',
                                                          'anchor_string_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_tab_processor_version': None,
                                                          'anchor_tab_processor_version_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_units': 'pixels',
                                                          'anchor_units_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_x_offset': '20',
                                                          'anchor_x_offset_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_y_offset': '20',
                                                          'anchor_y_offset_metadata': None,
                                                          'caption': None,
                                                          'caption_metadata': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_label': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_value': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_value_metadata': None,
                                                          'custom_tab_id': None,
                                                          'custom_tab_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'document_id': None,
                                                          'document_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'error_details': None,
                                                          'form_order': None,
                                                          'form_order_metadata': None,
                                                          'form_page_label': None,
                                                          'form_page_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'form_page_number': None,
                                                          'form_page_number_metadata': None,
                                                          'hand_draw_required': None,
                                                          'height': None,
                                                          'height_metadata': None,
                                                          'is_seal_sign_tab': None,
                                                          'merge_field': None,
                                                          'merge_field_xml': None,
                                                          'name': None,
                                                          'name_metadata': None,
                                                          'optional': None,
                                                          'optional_metadata': None,
                                                          'page_number': None,
                                                          'page_number_metadata': None,
                                                          'recipient_id': 72295,
                                                          'recipient_id_guid': None,
                                                          'recipient_id_guid_metadata': None,
                                                          'recipient_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'scale_value': None,
                                                          'scale_value_metadata': None,
                                                          'smart_contract_information': None,
                                                          'source': None,
                                                          'stamp': None,
                                                          'stamp_type': None,
                                                          'stamp_type_metadata': None,
                                                          'status': None,
                                                          'status_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_group_labels': None,
                                                          'tab_group_labels_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_id': None,
                                                          'tab_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_label': '/222c/',
                                                          'tab_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_order': None,
                                                          'tab_order_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_type': None,
                                                          'tab_type_metadata': None,
                                                          'template_locked': None,
                                                          'template_locked_metadata': None,
                                                          'template_required': None,
                                                          'template_required_metadata': None,
                                                          'tool_tip_metadata': None,
                                                          'tooltip': None,
                                                          'width': None,
},
                                                         {'anchor_allow_white_space_in_characters': None,
                                                          'anchor_allow_white_space_in_characters_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_case_sensitive': None,
                                                          'anchor_case_sensitive_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_ignore_if_not_present': None,
                                                          'anchor_ignore_if_not_present_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_match_whole_word': True,
                                                          'anchor_match_whole_word_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_string': '/333d/',
                                                          'anchor_string_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_tab_processor_version': None,
                                                          'anchor_tab_processor_version_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_units': 'pixels',
                                                          'anchor_units_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_x_offset': '20',
                                                          'anchor_x_offset_metadata': None,
                                                          'anchor_y_offset': '20',
                                                          'anchor_y_offset_metadata': None,
                                                          'caption': None,
                                                          'caption_metadata': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_label': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_value': None,
                                                          'conditional_parent_value_metadata': None,
                                                          'custom_tab_id': None,
                                                          'custom_tab_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'document_id': None,
                                                          'document_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'error_details': None,
                                                          'form_order': None,
                                                          'form_order_metadata': None,
                                                          'form_page_label': None,
                                                          'form_page_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'form_page_number': None,
                                                          'form_page_number_metadata': None,
                                                          'hand_draw_required': None,
                                                          'height': None,
                                                          'height_metadata': None,
                                                          'is_seal_sign_tab': None,
                                                          'merge_field': None,
                                                          'merge_field_xml': None,
                                                          'name': None,
                                                          'name_metadata': None,
                                                          'optional': None,
                                                          'optional_metadata': None,
                                                          'page_number': None,
                                                          'page_number_metadata': None,
                                                          'recipient_id': 4804,
                                                          'recipient_id_guid': None,
                                                          'recipient_id_guid_metadata': None,
                                                          'recipient_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'scale_value': None,
                                                          'scale_value_metadata': None,
                                                          'smart_contract_information': None,
                                                          'source': None,
                                                          'stamp': None,
                                                          'stamp_type': None,
                                                          'stamp_type_metadata': None,
                                                          'status': None,
                                                          'status_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_group_labels': None,
                                                          'tab_group_labels_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_id': None,
                                                          'tab_id_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_label': '/333d/',
                                                          'tab_label_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_order': None,
                                                          'tab_order_metadata': None,
                                                          'tab_type': None,
                                                          'tab_type_metadata': None,
                                                          'template_locked': None,
                                                          'template_locked_metadata': None,
                                                          'template_required': None,
                                                          'template_required_metadata': None,
                                                          'tool_tip_metadata': None,
                                                          'tooltip': None,
                                                          'width': None,
}],
                                      },
                             'user_id': None}],
                             },
}
```

Is there a value I am not setting or missing on the recipients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use this `/222c/` and `/333d/`  as your anchor strings for both recipients it seems to me.
These are strings to be looked up in your document and be used to anchor the tabs, but since you use them for both signers, they'll get the same tabs, twice, once for each.

You can either have different strings for different signers or use fixed positioning instead where you provide the X/Y coordinates instead of providing anchor strings.